Register a Pandas Dataframe to Azure Machine Learning: NOT_SUPPORTED_API_USE_ATTEMPT
I have been using the following code to register Pandas dataframes to Azure ML:
workspace = Workspace(<subscription_id>, <resource_group>, <workspace_name>)
from azureml.core import Dataset
datastore = workspace.get_default_datastore()
ds = Dataset.Tabular.register_pandas_dataframe(df, datastore, "output_dataset_name", "description")

However, starting today, I am receiving a deprecation error message:
    Message: [NOT_SUPPORTED_API_USE_ATTEMPT] The [read_pandas_dataframe] API has been deprecated and is no longer supported
    Payload: {"rslex_version": "2.22.2", "api_name": "read_pandas_dataframe", "version": "5.1.6"}
ActivityCompleted: Activity=register_pandas_dataframe, HowEnded=Failure, Duration=14.09 [ms], Info = {'activity_name': 'register_pandas_dataframe', 'activity_type': 'PublicApi', 'app_name': 'TabularDataset', 'source': 'azureml.dataset', 'version': '1.51.0.post1', 'dataprepVersion': '5.1.6', 'completionStatus': 'Failure', 'durationMs': 1.7}, Exception=NotImplementedError; read_pandas_dataframe is no longer supported. Write dataframe out as Parquet or csv and use read_parquet or read_csv instead..

Can anybody recommend the best way to register Pandas dataframes as AML datasets after this deprecation? Thanks!

The error is due to your use of the latest azureml-dataset-runtime and azureml-dataprep packages.
You can either install the azureml-dataset-runtime and azureml-dataprep package versions that are compatible with most operations, or, as suggested in the error, write out to CSV or Parquet and create a dataset using the latest SDK v2.

For the first solution, install azureml-dataset-runtime using the command below and register the dataset.
pip install azureml-dataset-runtime==1.51.0

Write to a CSV file using the code below.
df.to_csv("./tmp/csv/tmp.csv")


Create a dataset using any one of the SDK versions mentioned in the documentation, but I recommend using SDK v2, where you need to create a yaml file for the tabular dataset.
YAML
type: mltable

paths:
  - pattern: ./*.csv
transformations:
  - read_delimited:
      delimiter: ,
      encoding: ascii
      header: all_files_same_headers

Use the code below:
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes

my_path = './tmp/csv/'

my_data = Data(
    path=my_path,
    type=AssetTypes.MLTABLE,
    description="<description>",
    name="<name>",
    version='<version>'
)

ml_client.data.create_or_update(my_data)


The first solution (installing the specific version of azureml-dataset-runtime) solved the problem. Thank you!

Glad it worked at least 1 of the solution.
